# Navigate to the build sourcedirectory in azure devops build server

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm using the below powershell in Azure DevOps pipeline yaml file to view all the files in the Build.SourcesDirectory. But, run into the following error. When I try to browse for the following directory on build server to investigate build artifacts, I don't see it. How do I navigate to Build.SourcesDirectory using powershell in Azure DevOps release pipeline. I looked at following [msdn article1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/build-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#how-do-i-publish-artifacts), [msdn article2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?source=recommendations&view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) & [msdn article3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

***Powershell:***

```
  - task: PowerShell@2
  - powershell: |
        Get-ChildItem $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
```

***Error:***

```
Invalid file path '/home/vsts/work'. A path to a .ps1 file is required.
```

Any guidance is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [PowerShell v2 task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/powershell-v2?view=azure-pipelines). You have to define the target type:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs: 
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Get-ChildItem $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
```

Example: [Write an error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/powershell-v2?view=azure-pipelines#write-an-error)